# Are there any tricks for simultaneous equations I should be aware of?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I'm at the end of a difficult logarithms question and have ascertained the linear equations I need in order to establish x and y as the questions asks of me.

The equations are:

$x - 5y + 4 = 1$

$\frac {x+1}{2} = y^2$

Now I'm going through slowly, doing to each side the same thing, so as not to ruin my equations. I've got to....

$x + 3 = 5y$

$x + 1 = 2y^2$

I just wondered if there is a trick somewhere that would speed things up for me?

Thank you

Comment: So x is clearly equal to 5y-3, but I'm just figuring out how to go about the second one swiftly

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if my equations are not linear. Perhaps I should give the quadratic equation a try?

Comment: I'm attempting substitution

Comment: Please math jaxify your problem. What does all over in the second eqn mean? Whole squared?

Comment: It means x+1 over 2, sorry. Didn't want people to get confused think it meant just the 1 was divided by 2.

Comment: I will edit the question.

Comment: Please either see the help pages to learn how to format mathematics here, or at least use parentheses to make formulas unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll go away and learn how to do so

Comment: Here is the reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

You can see $5y-2y^2=2$ by subtracting the 2 equations. Then solve the quadratic.

Comment: So just to be clear, you multiplied the second equation by 2 before subtracting?

x - x = 0

-5y is a minus?

2y^2 is a positive in my notes.

and 1 - 0 = 2

I'm normally good at these but I feel incredibly stupid at the moment, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get you.

Comment: Sorry they're the notes I have and they're not making much sense to me either. I'm gonna go study again for a while and I'll be back.

In order for you to subtract the equations did you take further steps than those mentioned in my question? Thanks.

Comment: I can see this now, thank you. Could I see your steps for the subtraction? Mine was a page and a half, which is unnecessary.

So now I have y = either 2, or a half

Which one shall I substitute in, to establish the value of x?

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic above is standard and correct 
Therefore,  $x = -1/2$ and $y= 1/2$
Since $y= -2$, does not give an exact value of $x$,  which satisfy the equations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).